# Bloquear tecla f5 javascript

Tags: javascript

Bom, tal como o próprio título indica, gostaria de saber como faço para bloquear a tecla <kbd>F5</kbd> com Javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se o teu intuito é prevenir que o utilizador faça *refresh* no browser isso não vai ser possível. É o direito do utilizador fazer isso.

Se quiseres usar a tecla <kbd>F5</kbd> para outra funcionalidade então o código dessa tecla é `116`, só precisas ter um auscultador de eventos ao evento `keydown`.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (code == 116) e.preventDefault();
    else return true;
    // fazer algo aqui para quando a tecla F5 for premida
});
```

#### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx2cwwg5/show/)

Comment: Funcionou corretamente, Obrigado!

Comment: Tenha em mente que isso apenas vai interceptar a tecla F5...
Ctrl + R, Command + R e Menu>Refresh ainda funcionarão...